# secure sqlserver 2008 database by AD group

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to restrict access to a SQLServer 2008 database to users of a given AD group, without having to create accounts for each user?

If so, how do I do it?

Users will be authenticating with SQLS with Windows Authentication using their respective accounts.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can!

Just go to the Security\Logins->New Login... as specify your group in the "Login name" text box:
[image: New Login]

And them make sure to assing this group to an appropriate database user and role:
[image: User mapping]

Comment: doesnt this mean i have to authenticate with SQSL as this single login though? Users will be authenticating with their own AD accounts

Comment: I don't know what SQSL is and I'm assuming in your question that you mean you want to grant access to a specific database based on AD group membership, and if so, Regent's answer is correct. I've used this method many times. When members of the group access the database with their AD accounts they'll be granted access by virtue of their membership in the group.

Comment: yeah it does work, didnt realise it was this simple. cheers all

Comment: I meant SQLS (sql server), was a typo